# Updating a record in database

Tags: sql, delphi, ms-access, delphi-xe2

- Using `TADOCommand` to update a record.
- using `TADOCommand` to insert a new record.
- Name of table is `Board`
- Using MS Access database

I get an error

> Syntax error in UPDATE/INSERT INTO statement

I can connect and retrieve data just fine. Just never added or updated data before.

My database columns looks like this

```
ID (auto number)   
SN (text)  
CardType (text)  
Desc (memo)  
dbDate (date)  
Tech (text)
```

Code looks like this:

```
procedure TForm2.BSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
const
   sqlStringNew = 'INSERT INTO Board (SN,CardType,Desc,dbDate,Tech) VALUES (:aSN,:aCardType,:aDesc,:aDate,:aTech);';
   sqlStringUpdate = 'UPDATE Board SET SN=:aSN, CardType=:aCardType, Desc=:aDesc, dbDate=:aDate, Tech=:aTech WHERE ID = :aID;';
var
  ADOCommand : TAdoCommand;
begin
  ADOCommand := TADOCommand.Create(nil);

   // updating a board
   if NewBoard = false then
   begin
      try
        ADOCommand.Connection := adoConnection1;
        ADOCommand.Parameters.Clear;
        ADOCommand.Commandtext := sqlStringUpdate;
        ADOCommand.ParamCheck := false;
        ADOCommand.Parameters.ParamByName('aSN').Value := ESerialNumber.Text;
        ADOCommand.Parameters.ParamByName('aCardType').Value := ECardType.Text;
        ADOCommand.Parameters.ParamByName('aDesc').Value := MDescription.Text;
        ADOCommand.Parameters.ParamByName('aDate').Value := strtodate(EDate.Text);
        ADOCommand.Parameters.ParamByName('aTech').Value := ETech.Text;
        ADOCommand.Parameters.ParamByName('aID').Value := UpdateID;
        ADOCommand.Execute;
      finally
        ADOCommand.Free;
      end;
      Showmessage('Update Complete');
   end;

  //if a new board
  if NewBoard = True then
    Begin
      try
        ADOCommand.Connection := adoConnection1;
        ADOCommand.Parameters.Clear;
        ADOCommand.Commandtext := sqlStringNew;
        ADOCommand.ParamCheck := false;
        ADOCommand.Parameters.ParamByName('aSN').Value := ESerialNumber.Text;
        ADOCommand.Parameters.ParamByName('aCardType').Value := ECardType.Text;
        ADOCommand.Parameters.ParamByName('aDesc').Value := MDescription.Text;
        ADOCommand.Parameters.ParamByName('aDate').Value := strtodate(EDate.Text);
        ADOCommand.Parameters.ParamByName('aTech').Value := ETech.Text;
        ADOCommand.Execute;
      finally
        ADOCommand.Free;

      end;
      NewBoard := false;
      BSave.Enabled := false;
      NoEdit;
      Showmessage('New Record Added');
    End;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is advisable not to use SQL keywords for table and field names. `DATE` is a function in many SQL dialects. If you choose to use a reserved word/function name for a table/field name, you have to escape it in SQL statement: `[Date]` for SQL Server and MS Access, `"Date"` - for Oracle.

Comment: ok, i will change the DB to dbDate instead of Date and try that.

Comment: Still same error, But thanks for seeing that. As i am sure it would cause troubles in long run.

Comment: remove semicolons at the end of your SQL statements

Comment: that did not help, I know when using an TADOQuery i have left it on the end and it did not matter, but thanks